# How to use CREATE TABLE ... AS with Primary Key in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

From SQLite documentation for CREATE TABLE http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html:

> A table created using CREATE TABLE AS has no PRIMARY KEY and no
>   constraints of any kind.

So is there any general way to create table with primary key & other index information ?

Answer (score 9):

I suspect you're missing the difference between `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE AS` (otherwise known as **CTAS**).

`CREATE TABLE AS` allows you to create a table from the resultset of a query.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE PHILSUCKS AS ( SELECT PHIL, SUCKS FROM EGGS );
```

You could, instead of using CTAS, use a "normal" `CREATE TABLE` statement, then `INSERT` the rows manually. This allows you to specify the `PRIMARY KEY` and any constraints. eg:

```
CREATE TABLE PHILSUCKS
(
  PHIL   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  SUCKS  INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO PHILSUCKS ( SELECT PHIL, SUCKS FROM EGGS );
```

Obviously, you can also create indexes etc too:

```
CREATE INDEX EGGSUCKING ON PHILSUCKS (SUCKS);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have a template table and I want to copy its schema, so I need to use CREATE TABLE AS.

Comment: You can't do it with CTAS. If you want PKs etc, you'll have to pre-create, then insert. It's trivial to get the DDL for an existing table.

Comment: At no point today did I even consider that a post about SQLite would make me laugh. @Philᵀᴹ, you win the day (eleven years later).

Answer (score 1):

The `sqlite_master` table holds all info on tables and indexes of the database. Assuming the existing table is called `oldtable`, you can retrieve the table definition from `sqlite_master` as:

```
SELECT sql
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'oldtable';
```

In the retrieved sql field, replace the `oldtable` with `newtable` and run the SQL statement against the connection.

Then you can retrieve the indexes by:

```
SELECT name, sql
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type = 'index' AND tbl_name = 'oldtable';
```

Given that the index names should be unique in the database, mangle the `name` field to something not used, substitute *mangled_name* for *name* and *newtable* for *oldtable* in the *sql* text and run the updated SQL statement of each index.

Then you can just run:

```
INSERT INTO newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable;
```